# Where can I find the list of available runtime images for JFrog Pipelines?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I want to create a step that gets executed on windows together with Java 17. I am trying to avoid creating a [custom VM](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Creating+Custom+VM+Images) for this use case and to use a prebuilt image.

Is there an image for Windows that includes Java 17?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Runtime+Images, `releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/pipelines-w19java:17` is a Windows Server 2019 image that includes Java 17.